# How to get string in var as obj key in javascript/node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, object, key

Considering the following code:

```
let mystr = 'abc';
let obj = {mystr: 'bla'};
console.log(obj);
```

Why does this output

```
{ mystr: 'bla' }
```

instead of

```
{ 'abc': 'bla' }
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computed object properties is what you are looking for.

```js
let mystr = 'abc';
let obj = {[mystr]: 'bla'};
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a mega duplicate

```
let mystr = 'abc';
let obj = {[mystr]: 'bla'};
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
let mystr = 'abc';
let obj = {};
obj[mystr] = "bla";
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

`let obj = {mystr: 'bla'};` will be processed by javascript considering the name of the `key` as `mystr` as object is declared with `{key: value}` but if you need to render the value of variable as a name of the `key` then you need to use square notation like `obj[mystr] = 'bla';` as this will enforce the JavaScript runtime to render the value of `mystr` as a name of the `key`.

```js
let mystr = 'abc';
let obj = {};
obj[mystr] = 'bla';
console.log(obj);
```